# OpenLDAP schema and attribute for account type

Tags: ldap, openldap, schema

We have different account types:

- **Personal** - For employees
- **Sponsored** - For users that are affiliated with the organization but not official employees
- **E-mail only** - Only for e-mail usage (campaigns, etc)
- **Shared** - For offices or departments

Right now, we use an Oracle database to distinguish account types but are looking to move this information into LDAP.

Anyone aware of a schema and attribute that would be applicable to denote these accounts?

**Schemas currently loaded:** Default [OpenLDAP schemas](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin22/schema.html) along with the [eduPerson and eduOrg](http://middleware.internet2.edu/eduperson/) schemas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The employeeType of the inetOrgPerson objectclass would appear to be the appropriate field.

You may be able to determine E-mail only by lack of certain fields.

Comment: I ended up going with userClass, part of the cosine schema: http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ape/cosine.html